# How can I make my arduino print "the loop is running for the ....... time"?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

i want my arduino to tell me what time running it is E.g. "this is the 22nd time this loop has run." what command/s should i use?
i am currently using this code:

```
Serial.print("This loop has run ");
Serial.print(loopsRun);
Serial.println(" times.");
loopsRun++;
```

yes i have declared all variables, i just want to know if there is a way to check the last digit of any int.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you looking for the remainder of the division by 10 ?   Have a look at the % operator.
Anyway, the suffix st, nt,... is not appropriate with the message. It should be "the loop is running for the ...... time".

Comment: @MichelBillaud I agree, I'd discourage this type of error message in a code review where I work, but i think the "nd" etc. suffiixes are at the crux of OP's question, hence my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

22 % 10 = 2 you'd say 22'nd'
1022 % 10 = 2 you'd say 1022 'nd'

27 % 10 = 7 you'd say 7 'th'
457 % 10 = 7 you'd say 457 'th'

Am I getting the pattern right?  If so then you need a switch statement and a % operator

```
unsigned int remainder = loopsRun % 10;
switch (remainder)
{
    case 0: suffix = "th"; break;
    case 1: suffix = "st"; break;
    case 2: suffix = "nd"; break;
    <etc>

}
```

Comment: forgive the nit-picking : the C/C++ % operator is _not_ the modulus operator, but the remainder after truncated division.  Before C++11 the rounding for the quotient with negative numbers (like -5 / 2) was _implementation defined_  could return returning -2 or -3 and thus the remainder could be -1 or 1.
Now the standard states that "The quotient is truncated towards zero", and consequently -5 % 2 == -1, which differs from the mathematical definition of modulus. See  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic . The loopsRun variable can't be negative it should be unsigned.